# How to update more than one field in sub document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
{
   movies: [
          {
            _id,
            title,
            rating
          }
        ]
}
```

I want to update title or rating or both only if exists.

my query should be something like this

```
Movies.findOneAndUpdate('movies._id': movieId, { 
   movies.$.rating: rating, 
   movies.$.title: title 
});
```

But it doesn't support multiple positional operator.

The possible solution I thought was to send entire movie object and replace it as

```
Movies.findOneAndUpdate('movies._id': movieId, { 
       movies.$: movie 
    });
```

I don't want to replace entire object or I don't want to send entire movie object from frontend.

Please guide me with an optimised solution.

Comment: you can use `arrayFilter` to update nested array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with array filters https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243

```
 db.movies.update(
        {}, 
        {$set: {“movies.$[i].title”: "newTitle", “movies.$[i].rating”: 4}}, 
{arrayFilters: [{i._id: "movieId"}]}}
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Movies.findOneAndUpdate({'movies._id': movieId},{$set:{title:req.body.title}} { 
   movies.$: movie 
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.